# How can I use the same JS function in two different scripts?

Tags: javascript, html

I have these functions

```
function showNotification(response) {
  notification.innerHTML = `${response.data}`
  notification.style.display = 'block'
  notification.classList.add('created-notification-animation')
}

function resetNotification() {
  notification.style.display = 'none';
  notification.classList.remove('created-notification-animation')
}

 function clearInputValues() {
  movieTitle.value = ''
  movieRuntime.value = ''
  movieIsAvailableOnVhs.value = ''
  movieReleaseDate.value = ''
}
```

I want to use these functions for DRY coding, I have 2 scripts I want to use these functions in. 
I have 2 different HTML files that are being used, one for each script.

One script is main.js that holds these functions and more code, in index.html.

The other script is movieList.js that holds a list of movies, but I want to use these functions in that script as well, this script is in movieList.html.

How can I access these functions in each script without having to copy and paste the functions to the other script?

Is there a way to import/export?

I'm using node on the backend, but this code is all client side JS, so typical export default/export doesn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: add `<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="movieList.js"></script>` to your html.

Then in movieList.js, just call the functions where they are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include the file containing these functions to the HTML files, you can use these functions in other included JS files in the HTML.

Suppose we created a JS file named `utils.js` and we write all general purposes javascript codes like your notification functions, all we have to do is include this `utils.js` file in our HTML file.

Example:

```
<script src="/my_path/utils.js"></script> // This file containing my noticiation functions
<script src="/my_path/main.js"></script> // main javascript file
<script src="/my_path/myMovie.js"></script> // this files containing related my movies.
```

This is just an example. You can write your functions in any javascript file and you can use these functions in other javascript file or in your HTML. Just include the file containing the functions you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to import that javascript file that contains those functions in the HTML file where you want to use it?

Let's say I have a function in `test.js` file that I want to use in `index.js` file

If I import them in an HTML file like this it will work.

Note: Import the file with those functions before importing files that will use them

```
    <script src="./test.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import another file to your index file

```
<script src="./firstfile.js"></script>
<script src="./secondfile.js"></script>
```